# I still can 'delete for everyone' message on WhatsApp? Why?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I would like to ask..
Why can I still delete my message from whatsapp, even though the times already round in an hour?
If you guys know, please let me know too.. thanks

Answer (score 2):

WhatsApp has changed the way it works. You can now delete for everyone within an hour and eight minutes.

From [TheVerge](https://www.theverge.com/2018/3/12/17104726/whatsapp-delete-revoke-messages-time-extended-feature):

> WhatsApp has quietly changed the way its message deletion feature
>   works. Originally introduced in October, the WhatsApp “delete for
>   everyone” used to only allow you to delete messages up to seven
>   minutes after you sent them. WABetaInfo has noticed that the latest
>   version of WhatsApp extends that time limit significantly to **one hour,
>   eight minutes, and 16 seconds.**